# How do I create 2 frames in Java and Link them together?

Tags: java, user-interface, actionlistener

I just created a GUI, now I want to create another GUI and link both together.

So on the first GUI when the user selects 'next' button, the second GUI is displayed.

For this, do I have to create a new class and just create a GUI again?

Here is what I have now:

```
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Wizard {

private JLabel lblPicture;
private JRadioButton btLdap, btKerbegos, btSpnego, btSaml2;
private JButton btNext;
private JPanel panel;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Wizard();

}
public Wizard() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Wizard");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(600,360);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    MyPanel();
    RadioButtons();
    Button();
    Image();
    groupButton();
    frame.add(panel); 
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
public void MyPanel() {
    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(null);}
public void RadioButtons() {
    btLdap = new JRadioButton ("Ldap");
    btLdap.setBounds(60,85,100,20);
    panel.add(btLdap);

    btKerbegos = new JRadioButton ("Kerbegos");
    btKerbegos.setBounds(60,115,100,20);
    panel.add(btKerbegos);

    btSpnego =new JRadioButton("Spnego");
    btSpnego.setBounds(60,145,100,20);
    panel.add(btSpnego);

    btSaml2 = new JRadioButton("Saml2");
    btSaml2.setBounds(60,175,100,20);
    panel.add(btSaml2);
}
public void Button() {
    btNext = new JButton ("Next");
    btNext.setBounds(400,260,100,20);
    panel.add(btNext);
}
public void Image() {
    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("image.jpg");
    lblPicture = new JLabel(image);
    lblPicture.setBounds(200,20, 330, 270);
    panel.add(lblPicture);
}

private void groupButton() {

    ButtonGroup bg1 = new ButtonGroup( );

    bg1.add(btLdap);
    bg1.add(btKerbegos);
    bg1.add(btSpnego);
    bg1.add(btSaml2);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

- To display another window, you would create the window, be it a JFrame, JDialog, or what have you, and call `setVisible(true)` just like you do for your first window.
- You ask if your other "window" should be in another class, and likely that answer is yes. Since it will have a completely different set of behaviors and goals from the first class, better to separate out concerns.
- Having said that, what you plan to do, to show multiple windows is not always the best user interface design. Better often is to show multiple views using a container that uses a CardLayout.
- If you want to display another window in a *modal* fashion, that is, have the first window wait for the second window to be processed before allowing user interaction, the second window should be a modal JDialog or JOptionPane (a JDialog in disguise).

Answer (score 1):

I think for what you want to achieve, the use of a `CardLayout` would be appropriate.

This enables you to have multiple panels within the one frame with only one panel visible at a time and has functionality to 'flip' through the panels like a 'deck of cards'. So on initialising your frame you create the panels you want, and specify which one to start at then your next button will go to the next panel in the list.

See the [tutorial here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) there are also some video tutorials available on youtube.

Answer (score 0):

Write the two GUI's in different classes. When you start your program, start the first GUI.

```
FirstGUI frame1 = new FirstGUI("Title text");
frame1.setVisible(true);
```

Then, in the action listener code for the button you call "next"...

```
frame1.setVisible(false); //if you want to save the frame
frame1.dispose(); //if you want to kill the frame

SecondGUI frame2 = new SecondGUI("Title text");
frame2.setVisible(true);
```